Validate array of enums with Zod
Example enum:
enum Day{
  MONDAY = 1,
  TUESDAY = 2,
  ...
}

how do I validate with Zod an array of these type of enums?
z.array(Day) doesn't work
z.array(Day.MONDAY | Day.TUESDAY ...) doesn't work

From docs: https://zod.dev/?id=native-enums
enum Fruits {
  Apple,
  Banana,
}

const FruitEnum = z.nativeEnum(Fruits);
type FruitEnum = z.infer<typeof FruitEnum>; // Fruits

FruitEnum.parse(Fruits.Apple); // passes
FruitEnum.parse(Fruits.Banana); // passes
FruitEnum.parse(0); // passes
FruitEnum.parse(1); // passes
FruitEnum.parse(3); // fails

